# How to build a TCP server with erlang?

Tags: linux, tcp, erlang, udp

I am new for erlang, could someone please give me some guilds for TCP/UDP server with Erlang ?  and I have had one TCP/UDP client with c.

Comment: Google finds examples immediately, try it.  If you have a problem with code you're writing or don't understand something specific about one of the examples, then ask.

Comment: - [gen_tcp](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/gen_tcp.html) - [gen_udp](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/gen_udp.html)

Comment: thanks! Could you tell me: what is difference between gen_tcp and OTP ?

Comment: you should first read what those things are and see if you find any similarities before asking what the difference is.  You seem to have put little preliminary effort into this question.  Read some docs and write some code.  People have put a lot of effort into documenting things so you can understand them.  Where you can't, there's an opportunity for improvement.  You have to get there first.

Comment: A simple google search will give you a lot of options and examples (this is one of them: http://20bits.com/articles/erlang-a-generalized-tcp-server/). I would recommend you to learn some erlang (and OTP) before start asking this kind of questions. Any book/tutorial that you'll find over the internet, will help you understand very quickly OTP, gen_server (gen_tcp), etc. concepts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check this thing out :  [TCP Server](http://www.trapexit.org/Building_a_Non-blocking_TCP_server_using_OTP_principles)

But I would recommend you to start with gen_tcp and gen_udp modules first before getting started with OTP framework to design your server/Client.

Happy Erlang Coding :)