# Simple TCP server example in Erlang

Tags: erlang

Do anyone can provide me the code for a simple Erlang TCP server that can connect a client and get packet from the client.I'm new in Erlang so please provide the basic snippet.Thanks Beforehand.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to build a TCP server with erlang?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5778557/how-to-build-a-tcp-server-with-erlang)

Answer (score 1):

The [`gen_tcp` man page](http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_tcp.html) shows a very simple client and server right at the very top of the "Description" section.

Answer (score 0):

I think this [article](https://erlangcentral.org/wiki/index.php/Building_a_Non-blocking_TCP_server_using_OTP_principles) could help. It's a full tutorial about how to build a non-blocking TCP server using OTP principles very well documented and explained.

Comment: No Dear byaruhaf i already tried this its was complicated i need a basic example that connects client and can accept packets.